# Linking C++ header and lib file with Unity

Tags: c#, c++, header, unity-game-engine

So i am creating a simple game in unity where i want to use the tn gaming vest.

http://tngames.com/pages/Developers

I have downloaded the SDK from their homepage, this SDK is a C++ header and library file. What I dont know is how to approach from here on, using this for my unity project. Anyone know how to couple the files with my game so I can use the methods?

One problem is that i dont have Unity pro so i cannot use plugins as some people have suggested on some questions i found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Unity pro you can't use plugins and thus you can't use native library or external code.

Comment: Damn. Guess i have to use the free trial then. 

Thanks though

Comment: the answer is not correct any more (Unity free allows plugins too). I have added an updated answer to compensate. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

At least since Unity 5, it is possible for both Pro and Free users to create native plugins, and interface with the platform they are running on:

[Unity - Manual: Native Plugins](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html)

The steps are different for each platform, but they usually involve creating some kind of library (for instance dynamic `.so` under Android and static `.a` under iOs, which are the platforms I'm dealing with right now) and import the symbol into C# (everything is summarily explained in the documentation).

The process has it's own quirks, but it definitely works if enough effort is put into it...

Hope it helps (and removes some confusion that might be triggered by the, now outdated, accepted answer)